# Not find change stripe Bank account option

Tags: account, stripe.net

I'm unable to update my bank account information on Strip.com , I clicked on account setting option and I'm not see any option there, also read this documentation:
https://support.stripe.com/questions/bank-account-and-transfers
But not help. See this screenshot [image: screenshot]

Please help me how i can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Stripe Dashboard and go to the top right where it says "Your Account" and click on "Account Settings". Navigate to "Transfers" and edit your information from there.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/bank-account-and-transfers#updating-bank-info